# Align two elements in div container vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

i got a text and a button in a container. Both elements should be centered vertically. Furthermore I want the text to be set in the middle of the div and the button should be on the right.

So how can I center a text-element and put the button right next to it? I want the title to be side by side with the button.

My code so far:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #313132;
}

#headerTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

#menuBtn {
  right: 20%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="header">
    <p id="headerTitle">Title</p>
    <button id="menuBtn">Menu</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I want them side by side please. I updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the flex model and add some left-padding to the header of the average size of the button, so the p can be quiet in the middle.

example:(added a gradient to show middle)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  color: #ffffff;
  background #4a4a4a;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 50%),
  linear-gradient(to top,transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 50%)#313132;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  padding-left:2.75em;/* this should the width + eventually right margin of button so <p> can stand in the middle of container instead space left */
}

#headerTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin:auto;/* will center element */
}

#menuBtn {
margin-right:0;/* will pull to the right */
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <p id="headerTitle">Title</p>
    <button id="menuBtn">Menu</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome! That's what I needed, thank you :)

Comment: the solution  is very dependent on the width of the button but  the gradient magic trick stole my +15 points :( :))

Answer (score 3):

first to center `h1` add line-height equal to `header` height, and `text-align:center`

second, to center the menu use

```
#menuBtn {
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

where `top:50%` moves the menu DOWN with 50% of the header height , then `transform:translateY(-50%);` moves the menu UP with `50%` of it's own height and thus centering it vertically inside the `header`

see below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #313132;
 position:relative;

}

#headerTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 30px;
 line-height:60px;

 
}

#menuBtn {
  position:absolute;
 right:20px;
 top:50%;
 transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
 <div id="header">
    <p id="headerTitle">Title</p>
    <button id="menuBtn">Menu</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is fine

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the button inside the `<p>` tags.

```
<p id="headerTitle">Title<button id="menuBtn">Menu</button></p>
```

If you want to put some space between the text and the button right beside it, you can add some margin on the button like si:

```
#menuBtn {
  right: 20%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I need :/

Comment: What is it that you need? That's how I understood your explanation. Maybe providing a clearer explanation would help?

Comment: @peterHasemann This is exactly how I interpreted your question, you should try to be a more clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put them in same container inside another container
2. don't set the inner container width and height
3. set the inner container `text-align = "center"`
4. set outer container padding as you wish

   **Your layout will go like this**

> outerWrap{
>         innerWrap{
>
> ```
>   <p> , <h1>   
>
>            }   
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to research the answer yourself, trying to resolve the issue the best you can. There are plenty of resources on the net for this type of question just Google it.

> **For vertical alignment this is a good read [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).**

Anyways, as per your question going by the information you have
provided, this should prove useful.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #313132;
}

#headerTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#menuBtn {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* --- */

.float {
  height: 75px;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: #f0f;
}

.align {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="float">
    <p id="headerTitle" class="align">Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="float">
    <button id="menuBtn" class="align">Menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Regards,

-B